# Azure Machine Learning: What error is this?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using a Classic Web Service with a non-default endpoint for a Update Resource activity on the Azure Data Factory. This is the error I get:

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shK0R.png)

I didn't find any info on the web and couldn't figure it out myself. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-ml-update-resource-activity) website shows an example that I used by just filling in my values for mlEndpoint, apiKey and updateRessourceEndpoint:

```
{
    "name": "updatableScoringEndpoint2",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureML",
        "typeProperties": {
            "mlEndpoint": "https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/xxx/services/--scoring experiment--/jobs",
            "apiKey": "endpoint2Key",
            "updateResourceEndpoint": "https://management.azureml.net/workspaces/xxx/webservices/--scoring experiment--/endpoints/endpoint2"
        }
    }
}
```

There is no mention of a token that needs to be passed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error is basically saying the apiKey you provided is invalid to perform the update resource operation. Here is some posts for your reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3bb77e37-8860-43c6-bcaa-d6ebd70617b8/retrain-predictive-web-service-programmatically-when-do-not-have-access-to-managementazuremlnet?forum=MachineLearning

Please also be noted that if you modified your linked service in ADF, remember to re-deploy the pipeline as well to reflect your change in time.

Comment: I used the primary key for a non-default endpoint. You need to use the secondary key. That was the issue.